# A horribly difficult diffusion problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

We have a semi-finite glasstube, defined by the interval $0<x<\infty$, which contains water. At time $t=0$, the water is clean on $0<x<L$, but polluted with concentration $Q$ on $L<x<\infty$ . Determine the concentration of the pollution for all $0<x<\infty$ and for all $0<t<\infty$. The answer should be an error-function based result.

So I tried setting up the respective PDE:

\begin{equation}
\alpha u_{xx}=u_t ,\ \ \ \ \ 0<x<\infty\\
u_x(0,t)=0, \\
u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
0, \ \ \ \ \  \ 0<x<L\\
L, \ \ \ \ \  \ L<x<\infty
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here we have von Neumann conditions, so a reasonable ansatz is $u(x,t)=u(t)\cos\lambda x$. Plugging it in the PDE:

\begin{equation}
-\alpha \lambda^2u(t)\cos\lambda x=u_t\cos\lambda
\end{equation}

This gives the ODE, with u(t)=T:

\begin{equation}
-\alpha \lambda^2T-T'=0
\end{equation}

which has the solution $T(t)=Ce^{-\alpha\lambda^2t}$.

So the form of the solution is $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \cos\lambda xe^{-\alpha\lambda^2t}$

But since the coefficient $B_n$ is on an infinite interval (see IC. 3), then we have to assume that it is a function of  $\lambda$ and get using Fourier integral (referred to as "Fourier Sine Transform" on p. 651 - Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, Boas  M. 2nd Ed.):

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\int_L^\infty B(\lambda)\cos\lambda xe^{-\alpha\lambda^2t}d\lambda
\end{equation}

we can find  $B(\lambda)$  by using IC 3

\begin{equation}
B(\lambda)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\int_L^\infty Q\cos\lambda xdx
\end{equation}

But this results as

\begin{equation}
B(\lambda)=\lim_{C\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\bigg[\frac{Q}{\lambda}\big(\sin C\lambda-\sin L\lambda\big)\bigg]
\end{equation}

and therefore the final result is a rather incomplete and unsolvable integral

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{2Q}{L}\int_L^\infty\lim_{C\rightarrow\infty}\bigg[\frac{\big(\sin C\lambda-\sin L\lambda\big)}{\lambda}\bigg]\sin\lambda xe^{-\alpha\lambda^2t}d\lambda
\end{equation}

So I suspect this procedure is either incomplete, or merely wrong. Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The concentration has no reason to remain $0$ at $x=0$. The natural condition at $x=0$ is the Neumann boundary condition (particles reflect at the end of the tube), so $u_x(0, t) = 0$. The other condition would be $\lim_{x\to\infty}u(x, t) = Q$.

Comment: I see, so would the von Neumann condition almost always apply to infinite cases as this? I make respective correction.

Comment: Sure, the other condition is in IC 3.

Comment: You could define $v = Q-u$, so that $v$ satisfies the same equation and has constant $L^1$ norm.

Comment: You mean to create a different PDE?

Comment: $v$ satisfies exactly the same PDE. Then you could extend $v$ by symmetry to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $v(-x) = v(x)$. It becomes a trivial problem because $v$ satisfies the heat equation on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and the solution is obtained by convoluting with the elementary solution of the heat equation.

Comment: Can you show this in an answer please? Doing that reflection would give the same ansatz, only with a negative sign in front of it, so how I find the solution then is not clear.